# SQL ALCHEMY - How to return query(model).all() as a tuple of values instead of model instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQL Alchemy for my project but I'm having a hard time finding out how to simply query a model and return a list of tuples as a result.

I have a simple model:

```
class Security(Base):

    __tablename__   = 'Securities'
    id              = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ticker          = Column(String, index= True)
    company         = Column(String)
    sector          = Column(String)
    industry        = Column(String)
    country         = Column(String)
```

When I query this model within a session, I get a model in return:

```
s = Session()
q = s.query(Security).all()
```

If I simply print the query, I get a list of the model class.

```
[<models.Security at 0x7ff6eaf75a90>,
 <models.Security at 0x7ff6eaf759a0>,
 <models.Security at 0x7ff6eaf75940>,
 <models.Security at 0x7ff6eaf758e0>,
 <models.Security at 0x7ff6eaf75040>,
 <models.Security at 0x7ff6eaf750a0>,
 <models.Security at 0x7ff6eaf75100>,
 <models.Security at 0x7ff6eaf75070>,
 <models.Security at 0x7ff6eaf751c0>,..
```

So I've found a solution for now:

```
[(i.id, i.ticker, i.company, i. sector, i.industry, i.country) for i in q]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?
When I was querying my database with mysql--connector-python (or pymysql, can't remember), the results would be printed out directly as a list of tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get tuples rather than model instances you can query the underlying [Table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object rather than the model class, for example

```py
# 1.x style
rows = session.query(Security.__table__).all()

# 2.0 style
rows = session.scalars(sa.select(Security.__table__)).all()
```

Note that these approaches may not work for relationships.

If the application is designed to *only* handle raw tuples then there is little point using SQLAlchemy's ORM layer - use the core layer instead where you can work with `Table` objects directly.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I was looking for. I spent the entire morning searching for this.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to take advantage of the fact that for `select(Thing)`

- if we use `Session.execute()` we get ORM objects back, but
- if we use `Connection.execute()` we get tuple-like `LegacyRow` objects back

```py
class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "thing"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    txt = Column(String(50))


with Session(engine) as sess:
    query = select(Thing)

    results = sess.execute(query).all()
    pprint(results)
    """
    [(<__main__.Thing object at 0x000000FD8375C0D0>,),
     (<__main__.Thing object at 0x000000FD8375C160>,)]
    """

    with sess.connection() as conn:
        results = conn.execute(query).all()
        pprint(results)
        """
        [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')]
        """
```